# Graph of parametric vector equation

Tags: vectors, parametric

The question is asking me to sketch the graph of the parametric vector function $$\vec r(t) = \vec at+\vec bt^2 $$Where $t$ is a real number, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are constant non-parallel non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Putting some arbitrary vectors into Wolframalpha shows the general shape of a parabola which kind of makes sense to me but I'm a bit lost as to the general properties of the graph and how the shape of the graph would change with different vectors. Could anyone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: When $|t|$ is small the linear term predominates, so you basically get a line (slighly perturbed by the quadratic) that points in the direction of $a$ that'll form the base of the parabola. When $|t| \rightarrow \infty$, the situation reverses: you get two lines (one for $t>0$ and another for $t<0$) in the direction of $b$ that'll form the arms of the parabola.
Now, the norms of $a$ and $b$ will determine the "width" of the base of the parabola/the separation of the arms. The greater $||a||$ is, the wider it'll be, and viceversa for $||b||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our old friend, the parabola $y=x^2$ has vector equation ${\bf r}(t) = t{\bf i}+t^2{\bf j}$, where ${\bf i}$ and ${\bf j}$ are the unit vectors that point in the positive $x$- and $y$-directions, respectively.

The choice of ${\bf i}$ and ${\bf j}$ is just the choice of the direction and scale of the coordinate axes. Because ${\bf i}$ and ${\bf j}$ are unit length and at right angles, they give the familiar Cartesian coordinate grid.

There are lots of other choices though. I could have my coordinate axes meet at a $45^{\circ}$ angle, and have one of them measured in inches, while the other is measured in centimetres. Any point on the plane would have a unique pair of numbers - coordinates - even though they would be very different to the usual Cartesian coordinates.

The curve ${\bf r}(t) = t{\bf u}+t^2{\bf v}$ is given in terms of a coordinate system where one axis is parallel to ${\bf u}$, and the other is parallel to ${\bf v}$. The units of are given by the lengths of ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$, respectively.

The important thing is that any pair of non-parallel vectors, say $\{{\bf u}, {\bf v}\}$, can be taken on to any other pair of non-parallel vectors $\{{\bf w},{\bf x}\}$ by a non-singular linear transformation.

This means that the curves ${\bf r}(t) = t{\bf u}+t^2{\bf v}$ are all the same as the curve $y=x^2$, up to a linear transformation. In other words, they are all just stretched and rotated versions of $y=x^2$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes lots of sense. So would I be correct in saying that the relative magnitudes of vectors **u** and **v** would determine how "stretched" the parabola is and the direction of their respective unit vectors would determine the orientation of the parabola? Would there be any additional information I could put on the sketch of the graph with the given information (like the gradient of tangent vectors at certain locations, etc.)?

Comment: That's more or less the right intuition. There are also "sheer transformations" to take into account. They take a square on to a rhombus. Linear transformations can take squares on to parallelograms. The tangent vector would just be ${\bf r}'(t) = 1{\bf u} + 2t{\bf v}$.